# Order of executing requests with AngularJS's ng-resource?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ngresource

**books_ctrl.js.coffee**

```
myApp.controller "BooksCtrl", ($scope, Book) ->
  $scope.getBooks = () ->
    $scope.books = Book.query()
```

Part A: Initial Code:

```
  $scope.delete = (book) ->
    book.$delete()
    $scope.getBooks()
```

**Part A: Solution by @apneadiving:**

```
  $scope.delete = (book) ->
    book.$delete {}, ->
      $scope.getBooks()
      return
```

Part B: Initial Code:

```
  $scope.save = () ->
    if $scope.book.id?
      Book.update($scope.book)
    else
      Book.save($scope.book)
    $scope.book = {}
    $scope.getBooks()
```

**Part B: Solution pending**: How can I tell Angular to first complete the save or update respectively and only upon completion start with getBooks() ? Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552886/order-of-executing-requests-with-angularjss-ng-resource-pt2).

```
...
```

**book.js.coffee**

```
myApp.factory "Book", ($resource) ->
  $resource("/books/:id", {id: "@id"}, {update: {method: "PUT"}})
```

**books_controller.rb**

```
  # GET /books
  def index
    @books = Book.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {}
      format.json {render json: @books, each_serializer: BookSerializer}
    end
  end

  # DELETE /books/1
  def destroy
    @book.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to books_url, notice: 'Book was successfully destroyed.'}
      format.json {render json: {message: "Book was deleted."}}
    end
  end
```

**Rails Server Development Log**

```
Started GET "/books" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 12:53:07 +0200
Processing by BooksController#index as JSON
  Book Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books"
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 2.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started POST "/books" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 12:53:07 +0200
Processing by BooksController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"title"=>"Test", "author"=>"Tester", "book"=>{"title"=>"Test", "author"=>"Tester"}}
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "books" ("author", "created_at", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["author", "Tester"], ["created_at", "2014-07-03 10:53:07.627400"], ["title", "Test"], ["updated_at", "2014-07-03 10:53:07.627400"]]
   (23.0ms)  commit transaction
Completed 200 OK in 29ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 24.0ms)
```

Here is my problem: AngularJS seems to execute all requests at the same time. That way the `GET`-Request is executed prior to the `POST`-Request, an undesirable effect in my case.

How can I tell Angular to execute the `GET` only after `POST` is completed?

Comment: Can you include the code for $delete and getBooks?  Would be helpful to see the generated JS if it's legible.

Comment: I updated the code. See `books_controller.rb`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do:

```
book.$delete({}, function(){ $scope.getBooks(); })
```

Or even:

```
book.$delete({}, $scope.getBooks)
```

So you have full control of the order

Comment: Hi there! This works for `$scope.delete`. Already helped a lot. But now I am facing problems with the `$scope.save` which takes data from ng-resource. Do you have a suggestion for that as well (I updated the post)? Either way, I am going to accept your answer.

Comment: if you keep adding questions to your initial question once you have a first answer, it wont work, thats not of stackoverflow is supposed to work

Comment: You should: 1) accept my answer, 2) ask another question for save

Comment: Ok my bad, relatively new to stackoverflow. I am posting another question.

Comment: I posted a follow-up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552886/order-of-executing-requests-with-angularjss-ng-resource-pt2)