# Order of executing requests with AngularJS's ng-resource? Pt2

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript

This is a follow-up question to [Part1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547120/order-of-executing-requests-with-angularjss-ng-resource).

Part 2:

**books_ctrl.js.coffee**

```
myApp.controller "BooksCtrl", ($scope, Book) ->
  $scope.save = () ->
    if $scope.book.id?
      Book.update($scope.book)
    else
      Book.save($scope.book)
    $scope.book = {}
    $scope.getBooks()
```

**book.js.coffee**

```
myApp.factory "Book", ($resource) ->
  $resource("/books/:id", {id: "@id"}, {update: {method: "PUT"}})
```

**Rails Server Development Log**

```
Started GET "/books" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 12:53:07 +0200
Processing by BooksController#index as JSON
  Book Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books"
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 2.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started POST "/books" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-03 12:53:07 +0200
Processing by BooksController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"title"=>"Test", "author"=>"Tester", "book"=>{"title"=>"Test", "author"=>"Tester"}}
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "books" ("author", "created_at", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["author", "Tester"], ["created_at", "2014-07-03 10:53:07.627400"], ["title", "Test"], ["updated_at", "2014-07-03 10:53:07.627400"]]
   (23.0ms)  commit transaction
Completed 200 OK in 29ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 24.0ms)
```

Here is my problem: AngularJS seems to execute all requests at the same time. That way the `GET`-Request is executed prior to the `POST`-Request, an undesirable effect in my case.

How can I tell Angular to execute the `GET` only after `POST` is completed?

Comment: `book.$save();` would do put or post if you have the id, its automatic

Comment: You should take a look at the promise API to chain your calls. BTW I hate question with coffeescript code.

Comment: @Bixi you should filter `coffeescript` tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
Book.save($scope.book, $scope.getBooks)
```

Or:

```
Book.save($scope.book).$promise.then($scope.getBooks)
```